# Элементарный JS. Нужна помощь

Tags: javascript

Есть кусок кода

```
var someWords = ["clear", "business", "entertainment"];
function pickWord(someWords) {
    return someWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * someWords.length)];
}
```

Интерпретатор выдает

> cannot read property length of undefined

Но как же ундефайнд если я даже имя аргумента переименовал по уже объявленной переменной??

Comment: могу поспорить что вызываешь функцию так: `pickWord()`

Comment: Так и было, но почему тогда интерпрератор выдает ошибку не на той строке где есть проблема?

Comment: Это работает, потому что **в любую** функцию, можно передать **любое** количество аргументов

Comment: Все работает, спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в данном случае имя параметра совпадает с именем глобальной переменной и перекрывает его внутри функции.

Чтобы не путаться с этим, можно переименовать параметр и получить следующее

```
var someWords = ["clear", "business", "entertainment"];
function pickWord(words) {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}
```

Таким образом, значение параметра *someWords* определяется тем, с каким параметром была вызвана функция `pickWord`.

---

Если функция была вызвана без параметров: `pickWord()` то значение всех объявленных параметров функции будет *undefined*.

---

Для решения необходимо либо передавать глобальную переменную в функцию

```
var someWords = ["clear", "business", "entertainment"];
function pickWord(words) {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}

pickWord(someWords);
```

Либо убрать параметр

```
var someWords = ["clear", "business", "entertainment"];
function pickWord() {
    return someWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * someWords.length)];
}

pickWord();
```

В данном случае будет использована глобальная переменная.

Answer (score 1):

Не договариваете Вы чего-то. Все работает

```js
var someWords = ["clear", "business", "entertainment"];

function pickWord(someWords) {
  return someWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * someWords.length)];
}

var word = pickWord(someWords);
console.log(word);
```

Comment: а вот так `pickWord()` не будет работать

Comment: Работает, да. Я вызывал функцию без агрумента. Но не ясно почему интерпретатор выдает ошибку не там где есть проблема, а на другой строке?

Comment: Черт, я просто ослеп. Все правильно он выдает.